# svn update from exported files

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I have 2 networks, PRD and DEV. Transferring files from DEV to PRDis very very slow via network due to the security filters, proxies, virus scanning etc. I need to checkout my DEV SVN repo (about 40GB) to production.

Can I do following.

Assume initial/any checkout was reached to the PRD.

1. Export only the changes at DEV
   (Show Log -> select revisions -> select all files -> Export To)
2. Transfer the exported files (i.e. via USB Stick)
3. At PRD, update the PRD local repository from exported files

Is there a way to achieve this?

With `export` command above is not possible, because there is no `.svn` folder comes with `export`.

(Tortoise svn 1.8)

Answer (score 0):

If the checkout have reached the PRD, you can create/apply the patch:

1. Create a patch from DEV:
   `Show Log -> Select revisions -> Right click -> Show diferences as unified diff -> Save as..`.
2. Transfer the patch file to PROD
3. Apply patch to PRD repo